# need to check wheter multiple pid are finished execution

Tags: bash, shell, unix, pid

```
pid_list="21232 21231 43432" # same can be put in an array as well
```

I am running a bunch of commands in the background and obtained its pids using $i. How can i check whether it is finished or not.

Comment: Note that if you want to wait until one or all of these pids have finished, then checking whether they have finished is not the right approach.

Comment: If they are the only processes you have started, you can simply use `wait` to wait for them all.

Comment: I am checking this condition inside a while loop and if all the pids are completed, it will exit else i am using sleep 1m to wait for a minute ... this will continue until the upload is complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ps -ef | egrep $(echo $pid_list | sed 's/ /|/g') | grep -v grep | wc -l
```

If the output is 0, that means the processes are finished.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to query `ps` for information about a specific PID, or a list of PIDs.

This should do the trick in your case.  If this command returns anything other than zero, then at least one of the PIDs on the list is still active/not finished.

```
ps -p $(echo ${pid_list} | sed 's/\ /,/g') | tail -n +2 | wc -l
```

Explanation:

- `ps -p` accepts a comma-delimited list of PIDs to get info for.
- `sed 's/\ /,/g'` replaces space delimiters with commas
- `tail -n +2` removes the first line in the output, which are only headers
- `wc -l` counts the number of lines that are returned.